# How to move SQL row value to other row

Tags: sql

Like
tablename:db

```
Fname    Salary
AB       500
CD       1000
```

How to copy 1000 to AB that Salary
Not hard coding the amount

Comment: What database do you use ? Also it is not clear, please write how does your desired result should look like ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for updating salary of AB with salary of CD, you can try this below Update script-

```
UPDATE your_table_name
SET Salary = (SELECT Salary FROM your_table_name WHERE Fname = 'CD')
WHERE Fname = 'AB'
```

> You have to make sure there is one single row for "CD" in your table. If there multiple available, some error will raised.

This is just a sample Update script you can check the logic how you can update a column's value with another row's value. You can now adjust the query for your purpose accordingly.

> Remember, never to play with your real data using Update/Delete script. Try up on your test data first.